# How can I remove home folder for a deleted user in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux

I have deleted user i.e., hduser using following command

```
sudo userdel hduser
```

After giving above command I have just used grep command to check whether hduser is deleted completely or not .

[I have listed whether hduser has deleted completely or not then i got the below error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAOSM.png)

[So when I tried to delete hduser in home directory I got error message saying that cannot remove device or resouce busy as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqXAi.png)

So how should I remove the hduser in home directory also ?

Answer (score 1):

"hduser" folder was deleted in my home directory just by giving the below command by logging as root. My mistake was I have done that by not logging as root.

```
root@system3:/home# sudo rm -rf /home/hduser/
```

Answer (score 0):

By default userdel will not remove the home directory.

If you are looking for userdel to do it do it as:

```
userdel -r hduser
```

If you explicitly want to delete it you can do it as following:

```
/bin/rm -rf /home/hduser
```

Update:

1. Find the process using the file:
   using any of the following command will tell you

   ```
   fuser filename

   lsof filename
   ```
2. Kill that process if of no use:

   ```
   kill -9 processid
   ```

Comment: By giving first command I am getting this error                              userdel: user 'hduser' does not exist
                                                                                                                      I am getting this error after giving second command                 /bin/rm: cannot remove ‘/home/hduser/.gvfs’: Device or resource busy @anand

Comment: This is happening because some process is running which is using the mentioned file, you need to kill that process in order to remove that directory. I am updating the answer to tell how you can find the process and kill it.